# TCP/IP Frame header format

Tags: tcp, network-protocols

I used ethereal to capture some packets and I'm trying to make sense of the data. This is the output of 1 of the frames.

```
0x0000:  4500 003a 4564 4000 4006 df05 0a01 012b    E..:Ed@.@......+
0x0010:  0a01 0128 bfcf 3a98 e938 b9c8 e8a0 761f    ...(..:..8....v.
0x0020:  8018 05b4 ef33 0000 0101 080a 0005 ff31    .....3.........1
0x0030:  0005 2c31 6865 6c6c 6f0a                   ..,1hello.
```

The characters on the right is the ascii representation of the info on the left (Which is hex). The message being sent is "hello" and the rest of the information (or atleast some of it) is the header, right? What's the format of the header? I did some googling and found that this image: http://electronicdesign.com/site-files/electronicdesign.com/files/archive/electronicdesign.com/files/29/2099/figure_03.gif. Is this correct? According to the image, bytes 27-30 (761f 8018) are the destination IP but converting the hex to decimal doesn't end up being my ip. Am I missing something or am I completely wrong? Also how would I find the protocol number?

Comment: Ethereal is outdated.  Wireshark is its successor.  It will dissect the packet data and show you exactly what everything is. As for converting an IP, you don't convert the 4 bytes into 1 decimal number, you convert each byte into its own decimal instead. Best to use a function like `inet_ntoa()` that outputs a human-readable string from the raw bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Are your source ip 10.1.1.43 and destination ip 10.1.1.40?

I believe the info shown is not the ethernet frame, it is an IP package. The first octet is already the IP header.

To get a quick reference to the IP and TCP headers, you can use wiki

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Header

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#TCP_segment_structure

But if you want more details and reliable information, you should check the RFC directly.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc791#section-3.1

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793#section-3.1

If I rearrange your data in a 4 octets per row format

```
4500 003a  total length
4564 4000  fragment
4006 df05  header checksum
0a01 012b  source IP  
0a01 0128  destination IP
bfcf 3a98  ports
e938 b9c8  seq
e8a0 761f  ack
8018 05b4  windows
ef33 0000  checksum
0101 080a 
0005 ff31    
0005 2c31 
6865 6c6c 
6f0a
```

The first octet is 4 so you should be using IPv4. On the 3rd row, the second octet is 6. This is the protocol number for TCP. From these two hints i guess this is IP package not ethernet package.

And about ethereal, Remy is right, Use Wireshare https://www.wireshark.org/